# php regex validation

Tags: php, regex

just a quick question am abit rubish with regex so thought I would post on here. The regex below is to validate a username.

- Must be between 4-26 characters long
- Start with atleast 2 letters
- Can only contain numbers and one
  underscore and one dot

I have this so far, but isn't working

```
<?php

$username=$_POST['username'];

if (!eregi("^([a-zA-Z][0-9_.]){4,26}$",$username))
{
 return false;
}
else
{
 echo "username ok";
}

?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `preg_match` is the preferred way to perform regular expression matches. `eregi` was deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and its use is "highly discouraged": http://php.net/eregi

Comment: Didn't no that, thanks for link

Comment: Please give some examples of  valid and invalid user names. Your rules are contradictory (at least 2 letters vs only numbers).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use the regex

```
/^(?=[a-z]{2})(?=.{4,26})(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)[\w.]+$/iD
```

as in

```
<?php

$username=$_POST['username'];

if (!preg_match('/^(?=[a-z]{2})(?=.{4,26})(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)[\w.]+$/iD',
                $username))
{
 return false;
}
else
{
 echo "username ok";
}

?>
```

- The `^(?=[a-z]{2})` ensure the string "Start with atleast 2 letters".
- The `(?=.{4,26})` ensure it "Must be between 4-26 characters long".
- The `(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)` ensures the following characters contains at most one `.` until the end.
- Similarly `(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)` ensures at most one `_`.
- The `[\w.]+$` commits the match. It also ensures only alphanumerics, `_` and `.` will be involved.

(Note: this regex assumes `hello_world` is a valid user name.)

Comment: Make it start with more that two letters and it will be perfect :) "Start with **atleast** 2 letters".

Comment: But at the sametime it can only contains numbers, so the last chars must be only "\d._" and there can't be any number in the first part. Here is one based on your previous regex :

Comment: /^(?=.{4,26})(?=[a-z]{2,}[^a-z]*$)(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)(?=[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)(?=[^_]*_?[^_]*$)[\w._]*$/i  -  Each lookhead is in the order of the asked contraints.

Comment: i have made: `^(([a-z]{2})([a-z0-9]{2,24}))$` and works great apart from i cant get the single dot to work. anyone wish to extend go ahead.

Comment: @RobertPitt you don't respect the "only numbers" part neither.

Comment: Numbers are taken into consideration with `([a-z0-9]{2,24})` just the `_` and `.` for single

Comment: @RobertPitt, "az9az0za9z" is valid. Even if you accept the numbers, there is not only numbers at the end.

Comment: Do not forget to add the `/D` modifier. This is important because `$` will allow a final newline in the string, e.g. `"eviluser\n"`.

Comment: @Geert: Thanks. Did not know there's such a modifier.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking for a lot in one regex, this may be possible but it is not the best way, you want to let the user know why their username is erroring out.

```
function checkUsername($username) {
    $username = trim($username);
    if (empty($username)) {
        return "username was left blank.";
    }elseif (strlen($username) < 4) {
        return "username was too short";
    }elseif (strlen($username) > 26) {
        return "username was too long";
    }elseif (!preg_match('~^[a-z]{2}~i', $username)) {
        return "username must start with two letters";
    }elseif (preg_match('~[^a-z0-9_.]+~i', $username)) {
        return "username contains invalid characters.";
    }elseif (substr_count($username, ".") > 1) {
        return "username may only contain one or less periods.";
    }elseif (substr_count($username, "_") > 1) {
        return "username may only contain one or less underscores.";
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then to check you would do:

```
$validUsername = checkUsername($username);

if ($validusername !== true) {
     echo "An error occured: " . $validUsername;
}
```

This way the user knows there was an error and can fix it easier instead of being blind to what the error is. Also you should stop using [ereg](http://www.php.net/ereg) it has been depreciated use [preg_match](http://www.php.net/preg_match) instead.

**NOTE** the use of the !== to check, this also checks type since it can return a string (which would return true with a loose comparison). Just an FYI.

Comment: Thanks, it only echo'd "username ok" as that was sent back to the jquery function. I did have a list of the requirements the username needs, but I guess your way is better. I will give it ago :)

Comment: Added the 2 starting letters requirement.

Comment: `preg_match('~[a-z0-9_.]+~i', $username)` will return `1` for `foo@bar` as `[a-z0-9_.]+` matches `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, added the start and ending anchors to fix it.

Comment: I tested it, works fine but the underscore and periods dont work if I have one. Also I can have special characters such as '# [ ] ` etc

Comment: Instead of exploding and counting you could also use `substr_count()` (http://php.net/substr_count).

Answer (score 0):

The part where you said:

> and one underscore and one dot

would steer me away from regular expressions to be honest!

I would do something like:

```
if(!eregi('^[a-zA-Z]{2}$', substr(0,2))) {
    // .... check for only 2 dots here later ....
}
```

Comment: Simply because it would be far far easier to write a some `for/else` code at this point. I'm sure there is a regex for it but it'll be complex!

Comment: ☢☢☢ 2020 / php.net: "Warning This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0. "